# Open Safari window without toolbar in Safari Extension

Tags: swift, safari-extension

I am trying to build macOS Safari Extension, with the ability to open a new window without toolbar, like [tailwindapp.com](http://tailwindapp.com) do, in their extension.

If I use this function:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariapplication/1639493-openwindow
then toolbar is visible, and I can't find any variable to hide toolbar in this method.

If I try to open a popup window from js, when it obviously getting blocked. So probably need to open it from the native code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's no way to do it, over Safari Extension native code.
The only way to do so is through js onclick event (otherwise Safari will block popup).
The code for js is:

```
window.open("https://yahoo.com", "title", "status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=400,height=400,top=4,left=6").focus()
```